# Razor won't display value in Chrome, works most other places

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a form with several fields and am using the standard EditorFor template to edit each value. When I display in Safari and IE then the value for "Code" appears. If I show the same form in Chrome, the value for "Code" is not visible. If i do a ViewSource then I can see the correct value, just doesn't render on page. Any ideas?

```
public class PageViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Forename { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Code")]
    [RegularExpression("^[0-9]*", ErrorMessage = "Enter digits only for the code number")]
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

And my Razor is:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Code, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
     <div class="col-md-10">
         @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Code)
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Code)
     </div>
</div>
```

Update:
If I add the "Code" field in for a second time, then the second copy correctly shows the value. So confused:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Code, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Code)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Code)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Code)
     </div>
</div>
```

This is the View-Source:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-regex="Enter digits only for the code number" data-val-regex-pattern="^[0-9]*" id="Code" name="Code" type="text" value="22222">
```

Comment: Odd, what does it do if you use `TextBoxFor` instead of `EditorFor`?

Comment: If you view the rendered source code for the page, is it present? One thing I can think of is that maybe you may have a div that is missing a closing > just before the editor. That would explain the first one hidden, but the second one showing.

Comment: Does the same thing if I use TextBoxFor. If I repeat it X times, it will be blank on the first one and then populated on the others.

Comment: This is the output if I do a view-source. You can see "22222" but this doesn't render on screen  <input data-val="true" data-val-regex="Enter digits only for the code number" data-val-regex-pattern="^[0-9]*" id="Code" name="Licence" type="text" value="22222">

Comment: Is there a close to that `<input>` tag? Because right now, that isn't valid HTML.

Comment: @krillgar, XHTML requires a closing tag. HTML5 does not require it for void elements (elements that do not contain other tags). Void elements in the HTML5 spec are `area, base, br, col, embed, hr, img, input, 
keygen, link, meta, param, source, track, wbr`. However, that does beg the question... what is your HTML doctype?

Comment: Doctype declaration is set as:    <!DOCTYPE html>